# Java Multiple values for if statement in one go?

Tags: java

```
updated! see at the end..
```

I've got this small problem here.. From a method I will get a bunch of variables which I want to use for further testing, so for example I will get a variable: float xMax = 1

I use this variable to do some important test:

```
if(number > xMax) {
    System.out.println("test, test")
}
```

Now the problem here is that I want to dynamicaly add more variables but still do the check for each update..

```
int counter = 0;
float xMax;

privat void method() {
    if(counter < 6) {
        counter++;
        xMax = counter;
    }
}
```

In this code I will fill the xMax variable with the current counter number until it has reached number 6.0, so in the end the check will be only for 6.0 but all others that appeard during execution (1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0) will get lost.. when I test

```
(if(number >  xMax))
```

I seperatly want to test all numbers that appeared and not only just the last one. How can this be achieved?

Hope I've been clear enough, maybe I need to do it with some float list (no idea how).. I have really no clue, so thanks for any help!

UPDATE:

Consider that I want to store the values AFTER they have been created, in my code I've calculated the min and max values and now I want to store that x times:

```
if (xMin > xVertices) xMin = xVertices;
```

If the text file contains only one model this will execute only once.. if two then twice, if three then three times, and so on. now How would I use in this case the float array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an Array for storing all your Numbers.

```
//6 represents the amount of numbers you want to store
Float[] xMax = new Float[6];

privat void method() 
{
    //Fill the array with numbers
    for(int i = 0; i<xMax.length; i++)
    {   
        xMax[i] = i;
    }
}
```

Now that you have your numbers set call your tests:

```
    for(int i = 0; i<xMax.length; i++)
    {   
        if(number > xMax[i]) 
        {
           System.out.println("test, test");
        }
    }
```

++++++++++UPDATE++++++++++
If I understand correctly you want to store x values, but you don't know how large x is? Then you could use an ArrayList of Integers:

`List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

```
    for(int i = 0; i<xMax.length; i++)
    {   
        if(number > xMax[i]) 
        {
          list.add(number)
        }
    }
```

The result of this is a List of Numbers, which where processed by your test. If you want to get a number from this list call:

```
list.get(index)
```

Where "index" is the Position of the Number in the List.

Comment: Well, it's almost like I want It, I guess it's a bit more complicated.. I will update my question a little becaused I cannot just do i++ in my case..

Comment: Thanks, its getting closer.. does this have to be an integer arrayList? because I need float or double values, integers would be way too imprecise..?

Comment: Oh yes sorry. You wanted Float or Double. Yes it can be anything. Char, short, int, long, ... Just write Double or Float instead of Integer

Comment: Okay thanks a lot but I've still got some trouble adding the floats to the arraylist.. I've added another update, if you care to help some more I'd be very thankful..

Comment: Seems like the addition of values to the list does not work correctly. Could you provide the whole code so I can understand better?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake it actually works.. The problem is that I'm not passing the ayrray to the method where I make the if test.. but that's a different issue.. Thanks a lot for your help, all fine now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93288/discussion-between-nate-stone-and-disastercoder).

Comment: Thanks but no need to, as I said your suggestion worked without problem, I had a small bug of my own, that's why it didn't work :)

Answer (score 0):

The key insight here is that you don't want to compare **variables** but **values**. You can return a variable number of values from a method through a list, for example. Having that, you only need to establish that all values in the list satisfy your condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your method returns a bunch of variables, presumably in  a collection. So how all the variables except the last get lost is the real mystery here. You have to post the rest of your code I'm afraid.

Comment: made a small update, hope it helps.. essencially I just want to assign existing floats into an array without knowing how many there are in total..

Answer (score 0):

if you have added only one element to the list, this element is available in position 0, use get(0) instead of get(1). However, the exception says that your list has size 0. Do you actually see the printout in the loop-function in the console?

You should run your program in a debugger and inspect the array list to see exactly what goes on.

You have posted no code that shows the loop-function actually being called, if thats the case it explains why the array list is empty ...

Comment: I once tried to run a debugger but didn't understand what was going on.. well the problem is solved anyway, see Nate Stones answer.

Comment: Well, the purpose of a debugger is the opposite; to help understand what's going on :) Set breakpoints and inspect variables, it's not that difficult, and very helpful when "weird stuff happens". Happy debugging!